# Android put Cardview top of parent Cardview in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-cardview

how can i put `cardview` on top of parent `cardview` in below screen shot?

[image]

when i put image to `CardView` that cause of broken my view

correct view must be:

[image]

My xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/content_background">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/activity_main_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:titleTextColor="#ffffff">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
                            android:id="@+id/icon_signal_robot"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="center|right"
                            android:shadowColor="#22000000"
                            android:shadowDx="3"
                            android:shadowDy="3"
                            android:shadowRadius="1"
                            android:text="{fa-android}"
                            android:textColor="@color/quote"
                            android:textSize="30sp"/>

                        <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
                            android:id="@+id/icon_search_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="center|right"
                            android:shadowColor="#22000000"
                            android:shadowDx="3"
                            android:shadowDy="3"
                            android:shadowRadius="1"
                            android:text="{fa-search}"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="25sp"/>

                        <com.gigamole.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar
                            android:id="@+id/market_detail_navigation_tab_bar"
                            android:layout_width="90dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_round_circle"
                            app:ntb_active_color="#4527A0"
                            app:ntb_animation_duration="150"
                            app:ntb_corners_radius="50dp"
                            app:ntb_inactive_color="#dddfec"
                            app:ntb_preview_colors="@array/red_wine"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/signal_application_detail_activity_title"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="center|right"
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="19sp"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/activity_main_hearing_status"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center|right"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_antenna_white"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/signal_loading_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/loading_view_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/loading_view_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_description"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    />

                <com.zl.reik.dilatingdotsprogressbar.DilatingDotsProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/dots_progressBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:color="#ffee00"
                    android:radius="4dp"
                    app:dd_animationDuration="300"
                    app:dd_horizontalSpacing="7dp"
                    app:dd_numDots="5"
                    app:dd_scaleMultiplier="1.5"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/content_background">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/malam"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="230dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/background"/>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                        app:elevation="2dp">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/robot_dialog_icon"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/malam"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/dialog_robot_dialog"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frame and coordinator layout work in the same way: The first `View` is the most background, the next `View` is located on the top of the previous.

So I think you should just change the order of your `CardViews` in **xml**.

You also could try to use `android:elevation` in order to achhive desirable result.

After some tries I have achived [such result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMjBd.jpg)

My xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/malam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/white_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:elevation="10dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:translationY="32dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/white_card"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/robot_dialog_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: `android:elevation` not change my view

Comment: What about order of CardView in your xml?

Comment: i'm pasted xml layout on my post, could you test it?

Answer (score 3):

**CardView has default cardElevation=4**. Because of that all other Views coming inside the same parent layout of that carview will be below that cardview.

In your code, the cardview with id 'malam' will be above other views because of the default cardElevation. Try setting its cardElevation as 0dp to override that.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/malam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">
```

> UPDATE
>
> Setting 0dp will remove the shadow of that cardview. If shadow is required, then either
>
> 1. Remove cardElevation property from CardView "**malam**" & set "**android:elevation**" to the views with id "**linearLayout3**" & "**robot_dialog_icon**" so that value is greater than 4dp. 
>    (**Note : This works for lollipop & higher versions only**)
>
>    OR
> 2. Wrap "**linearLayout3**" & "**robot_dialog_icon**" inside individual CardViews.

Comment: set to `0` cause of removing `CardView` shadow

Comment: Setting 0 will remove the shadow. If you need it, you can set android:elevation="5dp" to the other views "linearLayout3" & "robot_dialog_icon" & remove the cardElevation from "malam". But elevation property works in android versions => 21.

Comment: Another workaround is to wrap "linearLayout3" & "robot_dialog_icon" inside individual CardViews so it works in all versions..

Answer (score 0):

I don't Understand what you want but I am thinking you want below thing.

If you want this type of like Image

[image]

Then use this Code.

**xml code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.softeng.aab.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    >
                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progress"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content_loading"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_description"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_owner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_networks"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material"
                        />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="5dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/card_view"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="right|end|bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin">

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_avatar"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UpDate :**

[image]

I think you require this

code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.softeng.aab.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    >
                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progress"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content_loading"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_description"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_owner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_networks"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material"
                        />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="5dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/card_view"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="right|end|bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin">

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"

            >
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_avatar"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

To Change `Image` in Round Shape just Change `ImageView` to `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView` it will solve your problem.

add below dependecies in `build.gradle` file to create Round image.

```
  compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but where is background image that was into `CardView` ?

Comment: i have only one background image, in both of may pasted images you can see that, its not `circularImage`

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy I think now you get it what you want like round shape Image.